# 01 Knapsack Using single dimension array for storing intermediate solutions

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have read couple of solutions to 01 Knapsack problem online. Each one of them is trying to store the solution for sub-problem chosen weights from 0..i and total weight w, when total weight is W. So basically they require a 2D array to store solutions to sub-problem. My question is why they are solving the problem for  a set of weights and thus adding another dimension. I am posting my solution which iterates over all available weights and build up the solution till the weight of knapsack. This requires using only a single dimension array. Am I missing some thing here. I am pasting my code below.

```
public class KnapSack01 {

//The Weight Matrix
int[] weight;

//The Benefit Matrix
int[] benefit;

//The size of Knap-Sack
int M;

//array to store solutions to subproblem
//B[i] = optimal solution for capacity i
int[] B;

//Array to print out the chosen weights
String[] chosenWeight;

int calculate() {
    B = new int[M + 1];
    chosenWeight = new String[M + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < B.length; i++) {
        B[i] = 0;
        chosenWeight[i] = "";
    }
    for (int w = 1; w <= M; w++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < weight.length; i++) {
            int b1 = benefit[i];
            int remaining = w - weight[i];
            int temp = B[w];
            if (remaining >= 0) {
                temp = b1 + B[remaining];
            }
            if (temp >= B[w]) {
                B[w] = temp;
                chosenWeight[w] = chosenWeight[w] + "," + weight[i];
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(chosenWeight[M].substring(1,
        chosenWeight[M].length()));
    return B[M];
}

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] w = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    int[] b = { 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    int capacity = 5;

    KnapSack01 ks = new KnapSack01();
    ks.weight = w;
    ks.benefit = b;
    ks.M = capacity;
    System.out.println(ks.calculate());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not correct because you can pick the same item twice(or more times).
Here is an example:

```
w = {1, 1}  
b = {2, 1}
capacity = 2
```

The correct answer is 3, but your code returns 4(it picks the first item twice).

It is actually possible to implement this algorithm using one-dimensional array, but it requires different order of loops:
The outer loop should iterate over items and the inner loop should iterate over weights from `W` down to `0`.